# iPhone OpenGLES App not Rendering

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am attempting to setup a simple OpenGLES project that doesn't use the interface builder and has as minimal code as possible. From what I can tell, the code that I have put together *should* work but it doesn't. I am basically at a loss now as to why it's not working.

Here's what I did:
 - Remove nib file
 - Remove reference in the plist file
 - Changed UIApplicationMain 4th parameter to @"AppDelegate"
 - Setup my files accordingly...

Full code is here:
http://pastebin.com/6DawjP0b

Thanks!

Comment: I'd add some `glGetError()` checks to make sure your FBO, etc. is getting setup correctly.

Comment: I put glGetError after every line inside initWithFrame and it returns 0 everytime. I also put it after some calls inside the drawView, and those are all 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `[Window makeKeyWindow];` to `[Window makeKeyAndVisible];` to ensure that the window is visible.